# iphone 4s - communications

Tags: iphone, ios, cellular-data

My phone Verizon (iphone 4s) is off contract/unlocked and I 
do not need voice.
However, I would like to use it to communicate over WiFi.
Is this possible (options) without a monthly phone bill..?
John

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48659/what-to-do-with-an-old-iphone-without-sim as well as http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3406 and http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/142648/can-i-buy-a-used-iphone-5-from-ebay-and-use-it-as-an-ipod-touch

Answer (score 0):

you can use certain apps to do this, things like google voice will provide you a virtual phone number which can do voice and sms.  as long as you have wifi, they do a decent job.

there's also a log of voip or messenger programs that do voice, but that's not so transparently behaving like phone number.

Comment: So, if I chose to give up the voice phone billing and keep my phone (not sell it to Verizon) it can still be used to check e-mail, SKYPE and facetime etc;..?

Comment: definitely -- while it's using wifi you have no need or desire for a cellular plan.  i do this with my previous phone.  it Does nag about activation, but i generally leave it on airplane mode with wifi on, to save battery.